# Google drive menus in chrome displays in different language

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

I am having a strange issue since this morning. Google drive menus in chrome displays in Traditional Chinese, while Gmail in chrome displays in English. OS is Windows 8.

I have tried:

- Clear chrome caches and temp files Change the language settings in
- Google account settings

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are the languages available in change language settings page?

Comment: @vembutech dozens of them available from Google account settings, including English, Chinese, French etc.

Comment: Then you can keep English and delete the other languages.

Comment: @vembutech Yes the only language left is English, but Google Drive still displays menus in Chinese.